Is there a way to have dialog destinations in back stack when navigating to hosted destination in Compose?
I have a project where I have a mix of hosted destinations (screens) and dialog destinations (dialogs) in Compose nav graph.
Sample nav graph:
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = "PostListScreen",
) {
    composable("PostListScreen") { PostListScreen() }
    dialog("EditPostDialog") { EditPostDialog() }
    dialog("SelectPhotosDialog") { SelectPhotosDialog() }
    composable("CameraScreen") { CameraScreen() }
}

I am navigating to EditPostDialog from PostListScreen, and then to CameraScreen. This pops EditPostDialog from nav stack so when I navigate back from CameraScreen with some image, EditPostDialog is gone.
Is there a way to have both dialog and hosted destinations in nav stack so this issue does not occur. I know this is expected behavior as per docs but I have different requirements in project.
Note: I have tried hosting dialog within normal hosted destination but that does not work as well.

I think declaring the dialog in the NavHost as you mentioned will make it hard to override it's behaviour so instead why don't you create it inside of PostListScreen() and add a state which which will indicate if the dialog should be visible or no and wrap it likethat:
if(shouldBeVisible){
   BasicAlertDialog()
}

and shouldBeVisible is just a remember{mutableStateOf(false)} and you change
it for example when you want to navigate to the dialog so instead you just show it in the same screen then anvigate to the CameraScreen from the dialog
like that you will be also able to decide if the dialog should be visible or not based on the data you retuned with from CameraScreen

Already tried that as mentioned in the post note. Does not work.
